# Xamarin Repeater inside repeater

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a Xamarin.Forms Project with the MVVM architecture.
I have a question about controls.

My ViewModel contains a property with a "Song" object, Song class contain a List of Paragraph and Paragrah class contain a list of string.

Song --> List Paragraphs

Paragraph --> List Lyrics

I would like to display the group of paragraph with Lyrics in one View using mvvm architecture (with binding).
Witch control can I use ?

---

For example :

---

Imagine there's no heaven

It's easy if you try

No hell below us

Above us only sky

Imagine all the people

Living for today...

---

Imagine there's no countries

It isn't hard to do

Nothing to kill or die for

And no religion too

Imagine all the people

Living life in peace...

---

You may say I'm a dreamer

But I'm not the only one

I hope someday you'll join us

And the world will be as one

---

Thanks in advance,

Bertrand

Comment: So you want to show the text only? All lines of all paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, only the text @Sven-MichaelStübe and all lines of all paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the text, I'd simply introduce a `Lyric` Property on the ViewModel. The ViewModel concatenates all lines and adds new lines in between,

```cs
class SongViewModel
{
    public string Lyric { get; set; }

    public SongViewModel(Song song)
    {
        Lyric = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, song.Paragraphs.SelectMany(p => p.Lines));
    }

}

class Song
{
    public List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

class Paragraph
{
    public List<string> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

And then bind it to the Label

```
<Label Text="{Binding Lyric}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"></Label>
```

Comment: If this answers your question, accept the answer (press the checkmark) so that the question will not appear as unsanswered anymore. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers